# Mat0-Slider ngModel not working angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

I am trying to implement the mat slider from angular material (angular 5) everything works well except ngModel does not change when I slide the slider, here is the code

```
<li class=normal *ngFor="let f of filters" attr.data-default={{f.default}}>
    <div>
        <small>
            {{f.name}}
        </small>
    </div>
    <mat-slider step="{{f.step}}" min='{{f.min}}' max={{f.max}} [(ngModel)]='effects[f.function]' [value]=f.default (input)="pictureManip($event, f.function, 0)" [id]=f.name></mat-slider>
```

for the typescript function, I did something basic ex

```
effects = [
    0,0, 0, 1, false, false
];
...
pictureManip($event, code, level){
    console.log(this.effects[code]);
}
```

The output is always 0... I do not understand, when I check with the others (checkbox), the ngModel gets updated to true / false but not for the slider, always 0...

Comment: What does 'f' look like?

Comment: The f represent the filters array entries ex : [{blur :0, step:1},{contrast:1, step:1}]...

Comment: Check. So f.function, is that an actual function in the object? Or a function reference?

Comment: a function reference, I mean the pictureManip has a switch loop hat check the function reference.

Answer (score 3):

The input event tells you what is happening with the slider thumb position. That is not the value of the slider's model. The change event gives you the changes in the slider's model value.

```
    (change)="pictureManip($event, f.function, 0)"
```